# How to use seState from child component?

Tags: reactjs

In the case, how to use `setDisabled` from child component ?

```
const ChildButton = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  return <div onClick={disabled ? null : console.log('do something')} />
}
```

import ChildButton from './ChildButton';

```
const Parent = () => {

  const controllSetStateFun = () => {
    // use the child coomponent setDisabled then I can re-render child component from Parent
  };

  return (
    <div>
     <ChildButton />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Usually what you'd do is to put the `useState` in the parent component instead, and send `disabled` and `setDisabled` as props to the child component.

Comment: It's called lifting the state up https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Define the state in Parent Component and update from the child.

```
const Parent = () => {
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false)
  const controllSetStateFun = () => {
    // use the child coomponent setDisabled then I can re-render child component from Parent
  };

  return (
    <div>
     <ChildButton visibility ={disbales} visibilityfunction ={setDisabled} />
    </div>
  );
}


const ChildButton = (props) => {
 

  return <div onClick={props.visibilityfunction} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

1. Take your state in the parent component.
2. Pass the set state function
   as a prop to the child component.
3. Call the setState function from
   the child component.

   const Parent = () => {
   const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

   const controllSetStateFun = () => {
   // use the child coomponent setDisabled then I can re-render child component from Parent
   };

   return (



   );
   }

   const ChildButton = ({disabled,setDisabled}) => {
   //you can access setDisable from here
   ...
   return <div onClick={disabled ? null : console.log('do something')} />
   }

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by passing the props also

```
const ChildButton = ({disabled, setDisabled}) => {
 

  return <div onClick={disabled ? null : console.log('do something')} />
}

const Parent = () => {
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const controllSetStateFun = () => {
    // use the child coomponent setDisabled then I can re-render child component from Parent
  };

  return (
    <div>
     <ChildButton disabled={disabled} setDisabled={setDisabled}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```